# User and group management in camunda admin webapp

Tags: admin, camunda

Is it possible  to manage which group is allowed to create and assign users in defined groups? Example of scenario is that currently logged user can create new users, but he can assign group membership only to groups that are created by him. If there is a group created by other user, current user shouldnt be able to access that group. Also this user should be able to see just users in his own group.